# Can iTunes sync podcasts to an iPhone without removing unfinished podcasts?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, podcasts

I often find myself wanting to sync my iPhone with iTunes when I'm in the middle of listening to a podcast. Currently iTunes removes that podcast from the iPhone while syncing.

Is it possible to configure iTunes to only remove podcasts played through to the end?

For the purposes of this question, assume I am halfway finished listening to the newest episode of a podcast and there are no newer episodes available.

**UPDATE**: this issue is no longer affecting me. Either an iTunes or iOS update (or something else) must have happened. Everything works swimmingly now.

Comment: Are you running iTunes on a Mac or on Windows? I am on a Mac and haven't seen this happen although I often sync while having partial listened to podcasts on my iPhone. Perhaps you can elaborate how you have set up your sync options.

Comment: I am on a Mac as well. It's no longer happening; I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This IS actually the case.

> What you should have a look at is **the selection option** that you have set.

For instance, if you ask to only sync the "*3 most recent unplayed episodes*", it might be that the one you are listening to will be replace on your iPhone by the newly released episodes that have been downloaded in iTunes. When the episode you haven't finished will be one of the 3 candidates to be synced (i.e. "when you have listened to all the newer episodes"), the listening will continue where you were the last time you listen to it.

**EDIT after the EDIT of the Question :**

Hm, ok, with this edit my answer is not right anymore BUT i think you should have a way have it work as you want. If you select for instance "the oldest unread", the one you are listening to will be kept on the iPhone (if you listen to the episodes in order that they are realeased) Another trick is to use the checkboxes on the left of each episode and set the preference to "Sync only checked"

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. I edited the question to clarify that this occurs with the single newest episode in a podcast.